# Storing information in quick.db then sending it

Tags: bots, discord.js, quick.db

I' am using quick.db to store objects in the database using

```js
db.set('object', 'A random text')
```

So how would I store an `argument`

```js
db.set('argument', args.slice(1).join(" ")) // This won't work I guess
```

After storing an argument into the database I want to push it to the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure because you provided so little information, but I'm guessing your issue is that the args is meant to be a dictionary, and you are currently joining it to a string.

```
// Setting an object in the database:
db.set('userInfo', { difficulty: 'Easy' })
// -> { difficulty: 'Easy' }
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ye, I replaced `{ difficulty: 'Easy' }` with args I defined. Thanks